# Oracle SQL - query results are inconsistent with when query variable is integer versus string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database field called 'svc_id_value' which has both alphanumeric values and integer values stored in it.

I have a query to search for detail related to this service id.  The query works fine when my input variable is an integer, but when I try the same query with an alphanumeric string, the results come back empty.  The field (svc_id_value) in question VARCHAR2(30Byte).  I can successfully filter for the alphanumeric variable in Oracle SQL Developer when in the Data view, but when I query it in SQL Developer, the results come back empty.

**Working Query (string is Integer -- searching for s.svc_id_value='555555'):**

```
    SELECT * 
    from svc s, status_types stat, service_types st,
    billing_types bt, account ax, building pp, locations ll, 
    ref_countries cx 
    WHERE 
    s.svc_status = stat.status_type 
    and stat.tablename='service' 
    and s.svc_type = st.service_type 
    and s.svc_billing_type = bt.billing_type 
    and ax.account_id = s.svc_account_id 
    and pp.bldg_id = s.svc_bldg_id 
    and ll.location_id = s.svc_location_id 
    and cx.id = ll.country_id 
    and s.svc_id_value ='555555';
```

**Non-Working Query (string is Alphanumeric -- searching for s.svc_id_value='88888888-ABC'):**

```
    SELECT * 
    from svc s, status_types stat, service_types st,
    billing_types bt, account ax, building pp, locations ll, 
    ref_countries cx 
    WHERE 
    s.svc_status = stat.status_type 
    and stat.tablename='service' 
    and s.svc_type = st.service_type 
    and s.svc_billing_type = bt.billing_type 
    and ax.account_id = s.svc_account_id 
    and pp.bldg_id = s.svc_bldg_id 
    and ll.location_id = s.svc_location_id 
    and cx.id = ll.country_id 
    and s.svc_id_value ='88888888-ABC';
```

To confirm that querying by alphanumeric variable works, the following simple query successfully returns a result:

```
    SELECT * from svc s WHERE s.svc_id_value='88888888-ABC'
```

I don't understand why the query would work with an integer, but fail when it is alphanumeric.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've gone to the effort of formatting it, primarily to check what else svc_id_value was used in. These queries using old style joins are really difficult to read, you should endeavour to use the more modern style joins.

Comment: So because your joins are all inner joins, any one of those tables (aside from svc) could have rows which join with the svc row for '555555' but not '88888888-ABC'. So you'd expect to get zero rows back in that case. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot this kind of issue, I'd change all the inner joins to outer joins, like so:

```
SELECT * 
from svc s
LEFT JOIN status_types stat
    ON s.svc_status = stat.status_type 
    AND stat.tablename='service' 
LEFT JOIN service_types st
    ON s.svc_type = st.service_type 
LEFT JOIN billing_types bt
    ON s.svc_billing_type = bt.billing_type 
LEFT JOIN account ax
    ON ax.account_id = s.svc_account_id 
LEFT JOIN building pp
    ON pp.bldg_id = s.svc_bldg_id 
LEFT JOIN locations ll
    ON ll.location_id = s.svc_location_id 
LEFT JOIN ref_countries cx 
    ON cx.id = ll.country_id 
WHERE s.svc_id_value ='88888888-ABC';
```

This way, you should get a row back, and you can browse through the results. At least one of the joined tables will have null values, and that's why you're getting zero rows back in your original inner-join query.

Comment: Thank you!  I need to investigate why one of the tables ended up having null values, but at least I'm getting a result back.